# How can I prevent duplicate values in SQL?

Tags: sql

I can't think of a good title for this question but here goes..

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT
  J.SRV_JOB_ID,
  C.UNIT_COST * C.QTY AS COST_PRICE,
  E.SERIAL_NO
FROM
  SRV_JOB J
  LEFT JOIN SRV_JOB_COST C       ON C.SRV_JOB_ID       = J.SRV_JOB_ID
  LEFT JOIN SRV_JOB_EQUIPMENT JE ON JE.SRV_JOB_ID      = J.SRV_JOB_ID
  LEFT JOIN SRV_EQUIPMENT E      ON E.SRV_EQUIPMENT_ID = JE.SRV_EQUIPMENT_ID
WHERE
  j.srv_job_id = 52423
```

which is somewhat simplified for the purpose of the question, and gives these results;

```
srv_job_id  cost_price serial_no
52423       89         400887
52423       89         400888
52423       89         400889
```

because there is one job with an id of 52423 and a cost of 89, but there are three associated serial numbers.

There is nothing wrong with the result, but it is misleading because it looks like each serial number has a cost of 89, when in fact the total cost for all three is 89.

How can I prevent the cost of 89 being duplicated? I can't change the database schema, but i can change the query.

The result i would like would be

```
srv_job_id  cost_price serial_no
52423       89         400887
52423       null       400888
52423       null       400889
```

Comment: Do a PIVOT and put all the serial numbers in one column?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you want your output to look like? Right now I am a little confused as to what you mean by "prevent the cost of 89 from being duplicated".

Comment: Your `cost_price` is calculated, think about changing that. What is the relation between `cost_price` and `serial_no` you are looking for?

Comment: Would you like to get the aggregated cost_price? So that the system is giving you the sum of the cost_price? 
What would you like your query to return?

Comment: Perhaps it would be less misleading if you change the alias COST_PRICE in the result set to something like TOTAL_JOB_PRICE. As you say, "There is nothing wrong with the result."

Comment: Also, what RDBMS and version?  SQL is the language, and the different databases implement it slightly differently.

Comment: Is there a way I can calculate the cost only for the first entry? I need to get rid of the duplicates because I am summing the whole column. I'm actually loading this into Qlikview.

Comment: The database is Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 1):

I've broken it into two separate queries. One to list the job(s) details and one to list the serial numbers for each job.

Thanks for you help. Your comments led me to thinking about the problem differently.